# What does it mean to describe the partition defined by the equivalence class?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Question:
Is this relation an equivalence relation?  If yes, describe the partition defined by the equivalence classes. Justify your answer: The domain is the set of all integers. xEy if x + y is even. (An integer z is even if z = 2k for some integer k.)

So for a relationship to be an equivalence relation it must be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. How would I apply it to this problem? Also, I'm don't quite understand what it means by describing the partition.

Comment: Are there two equivalence classes - the odds and the evens? I'm trying this for practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x + y$ is even, is $y + x$ even?
Is $x + x$ even, for all $x$?
If $x + y$ is even, and $y + z$ is even, is $x + z$ even?

Proving the above will allow you to conclude that this is an equivalent relation. They are asking you to determine what the *equivalence classes* are. Every integer is in exactly one class, with all the other "related" integers. To what class does 7 belong? 4? -3?

You might also find [this page](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MTH_220_Discrete_Math/6%3A_Relations/6.3%3A_Equivalence_Relations_and_Partitions) helpful, especially the example of people with the same last name.

Comment: Just want to double-check would all the above conditions evaluate to true?

Comment: There is almost no work to do. If $x + y$ is even, then $x + y = 2n$ for some *n*. But $x + y = y + x$ by the symmetric property... similar for the second condition. The third takes a few steps, but you can get $x + z = 2(...$

Answer (score 1):

"Describing the partition" of a set A given equivalence relations R1...Rn means to define each of the equivalence classes in the partitioned set. Any members of A which do not belong to one of the equivalence classes form a final equivalence class: their equivalence relation is that they do not relate under any of the relations R1...Rn.

This example can be confusing because ***pairs*** of integers belong in an equivalence class (or not), rather than individual integers, so we must define A to be the set of all pairs of integers.

- Let A be the set of pairs of integers.
- xEy divides A into two equivalence classes:

  - Class 1: x and y have the same parity
  - Class 2: x and y do not have the same parity